# "$(document).on" not triggering after event.stopPropagation and "$(a).on" not triggering for new elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, jquery-plugins, jquery-events

I'm trying to write a chrome extension (for casperjs testing). A part of the extension needs to bind to the `click` event which I'm doing like this:

```
$(document).on('click', 'a', null, handler)
```

This works great for all links, including any newly created elements. Problem is if a link has it's own `click` handler that calls the `event.stopPropagation()` method then the `.on` does **not** trigger the handler.

The workaround is I bind to the `a` elements like this:

```
$('a').on('click', null, null, handler)
```

This works fine and triggers the `handler` even if another event handler calls the `event.stopPropagation()` method. Problem is it does not work for **dynamically** created elements. So, any new elements created do not trigger the handler.

So I need something that has the functionality of the `$(document).on` method that triggers for dynamically created elements, but which also triggers regardless the `event.stopPropagation()` method.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Any ideas?

Event handling is separated in two phases: [capturing phase and bubbling phase](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html):

> ```
>                  | |  / \
> -----------------| |--| |-----------------
> | element1       | |  | |                |
> |   -------------| |--| |-----------     |
> |   |element2    \ /  | |          |     |
> |   --------------------------------     |
> |        W3C event model                 |
> ------------------------------------------
> ```

By default event handlers are bound to listen to the bubbling phase (event handlers bound with jQuery as well).

To react to the event before the element's own event handler is called, you have to bind the handler to the capturing phase. Note that especially older IE browsers don't support this.

Since jQuery doesn't let you do this, you have to use [the DOM API directly](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener):

```
document.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  // test whether event originates inside <a> first 
  // (search on SO to find out how)
  // then:
  handler.call(event.target, event);
}, true);
```

```js
document.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  if (event.target.nodeName !== 'BUTTON') {
    return;
  }
  console.log('Called first.');
}, true);
document.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  if (event.target.nodeName !== 'BUTTON') {
    return;
  }
  console.log('Called last.');
});
document.querySelector('button').onclick = function(event) {
  console.log('Called in between (could cancel bubbling here)');
  // event.stopPropagation();
};
```

```html
<button>Click me and look at the console</button>
```

Comment: yes, this seems to work for both case! thank you so much for the answer and explanation.