# jquery "on click" on button inside tab

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a jquery problem : I have jquery tabs on my page, and inside each tab there is a span with a class. Now, I create another tab dynamically with span inside, with same class, but it doesn't work.

This code work fine with existants tabs, but not on the dynamically created tab :

```
$('.editLibelleCategorie').on('click', function()
{
    console.log('1');
});
```

Now if I try this code, it doesn't work for existants tab :

```
// validation form modif libellé catégorie
$(document).on('click', '.editLibelleCategorie', function(e)
{
    console.log('1');
});
```

My html code :

```
<li class="sortable" id="2" data-idCategorie="2" data-libelleCategorie="cat" data-ordreCategorie="4">
    <a href="#tab2">
        <span class="button small aqua button-3d effect fill fa fa-pencil editLibelleCategorie" data-idCategorie="2" data-libelleCategorie="cat"></span>

        <span class="button small red button-3d effect fill fa fa-minus deleteCustomCategorie" data-idCategorie="2"></span>

        <br><span id="libelleCategorie_2">cat</span>
    </a>
</li>
```

It's like the "document" element selector don't work in jquery tab ...

Can someone help me ?

Thanks in advance, and sorry for my english ...

Comment: Can you share HTML also, so that it becomes easy to understand.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=jquery+event+handler+dynamic+content

Comment: It might be that onClick event propagation is being stopped, therefore listening on the whole document for this event won't solve your problem

Comment: @MarcinZareba so what can I do ?

Comment: @Thomas This might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33598935/4488333

Comment: You can still bind the EH again when you dynamically create a new `editeLibelleCategorie`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem, so i solve this way:

You add the event after create the new dynamic tab with this code.

```
$('.editLibelleCategorie').attr('onclick','functionName()');
```

This works fine for me.